# How does match_parent work?

Tags: android, performance, android-layout

As far as I've understood Android's View rendering process, the root Layout will start the measurement and ask each of its children for it's size. If one of them is a Viewgroup itself, it will again ask the children, which either just return their set size, or calculate it if they're set to `wrap_content`.

Now how does that work with `match_parent`? The view can't calculate it's size since it has to know the parent's size first, right? So the parent would have to calculate it's own size and then send that to the child, which then can go on with it's own layout.
Does that make `match_parent` a little more inefficient than `wrap_content` or even fixed dp-values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, `match_parent` says that "Hi parent, I want to be as big as **your left available space**".For example, if ViewGroup Parent has two children: child A at index 0 with `wrap_content` and child B at index 1 with `match_parent`. And A says he wants to be 100px wide, then the width of B will be : total width of Parent - padding of Parent - margin of A - 100px - margin of B

Comment: But it still has to ask the child once, then do all the other calculations and then come back to the child again, doesn't it?

Comment: No. if there's a 3rd child at index 2, it will never be visible because child B will fill all available space of parent.